# Show and Hide a dialog clicking on the title bar

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

Do you have a solution for adding a method to every dialog open without changing the dialog() initialisation code ?

The objective is to add this code after a dialog initialisation :

```
$(".ui-dialog-titlebar").click(function() {$(this).siblings().toggle()})
```

In order to add a toggle feature to the dialog clicking on the header (very usefull to see what's behind) I know I can loose the drag feature but I don't know how to detect drag and prevent the toggle feature (that's another point)

I want to add this feature without changing the 239 dialog({...}) functions in my app... Thank you very much for your help.

**Solution #1 thanks to @Alex Kiselev :**

```
$('body').on('click', '.ui-dialog-titlebar', function() { 
        $(this).siblings().toggle();
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try something like:

```
$('body').on('click', '.ui-dialog-titlebar', function() { 
    $(this).siblings().toggle();
});
```

Comment: Excellent, it works ! any idea to keep the draggable ?

Comment: It actually don't run this event when I drag ! So the solution is perfect !